# Drupal 8 load term by substring

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

Drupal 8 has term method loadproperties which works for custom fields; however, how can I use it (or can I use it) to load by substrings. For example if I have a field: field_full_name and I want to load all terms that start with a string "David*" is this possible ... if not how?

Thanks ~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the SQL operator `LIKE` in an entity query and append the wildcard `%` to the string:

```
$result = \Drupal::entityQuery('taxonomy_term')
  ->condition('name', 'david%', 'LIKE')
  ->condition('vid', 'tags')
  ->execute();

$terms = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
  ->getStorage('taxonomy_term')
  ->loadMultiple($result);
```